# Coprimes and Congruence

Tags: congruences

I need help getting a proof, I don't want solution to the problem just help guiding me to complete the proof.

> Suppose $m,n$ are coprime, Prove that $a \equiv b \mod{mn}$ if and only if:
>
> $a \equiv b \mod{m}$, and
>
> $a \equiv b \mod{n}$.

Comment: Well it's if and only if claim so can you do either of the directions?

Comment: What do you already know?  Bezout's identity, Euclid's Lemma, any properties of lcm's?

Comment: I know only Bezout's identity and Euclid's Lemma

Comment: Then you can use [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/692880/242) to infer $\,(m,n)=1,\,\ m,n\mid a-b\,\Rightarrow\, mn\mid a-b.\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**
$$a=mk\\b=mt\\a=np\\b=nl$$